# ZSH not showing/keeping history even though I have the various history settings

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, history

I have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
# history
HISTSIZE=50000
SAVEHIST=100000
HISTFILE=~/.cache/zsh/.histfile

# plugins
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions zsh-syntax-highlighting)

# user configuration
setopt autocd
unsetopt beep
bindkey -v

# preferred editor
export EDITOR='nvim'

# include exports
if [ -f ~/.config/zsh/.exports ]; then
  source ~/.config/zsh/.exports
fi

# include aliases
if [ -f ~/.config/zsh/.aliases ]; then
  source  ~/.config/zsh/.aliases
fi
```

And the directory `~/.cache/zsh` does exist.

Yet, history isn't kept around, when I start typing a command I know for certain I've typed before, I don't get any auto-completion, or greyed out version of the command.

What am I missing?

Comment: *auto-completion, or greyed out version of the command* would need some code to load those *plugins*  you store in that `$plugins` array some way or another. There are no such *plugins* in zsh, that may be something you can download from some 3rd party software such as oh-my-zsh.

Comment: Oh I see! What's the point of the `HISTFILE` setting if that's the case? Does it simply exist for plugins to make use of?

Comment: No, that sets the history file to store and load the saved history from, as used by many zsh widgets including those bound to up and down or `?` and `/` to search in vi mode or the `fc` builting command. History likely works for you, just not those 3rd party plugins which you are not loading.

Comment: Thanks, got you. Want to reply so that I can make as answer?